# Remove an item from List

Tags: java, collections

i am removing an Student object from ArrayList of Students, this is my code, below is the Student.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package corejava.list;

/**
 * 
 * @author Rahul 
 */

public class Student {
private int id;
private String name;

public Student(int id,String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Student(int id){
    this.id = id;        
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return this.getId() * 37;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();
    strb.append("\tID : ").append(this.getId()).append(", NAME : ").append(this.getName());
    return strb.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object studentOne){
    Student student = (Student) studentOne;
    boolean flag = false;
    if(this.getId() == student.getId()){
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

This is my Class which has a main method,

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package corejava.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * 
 * @author Rahul
 */



public class RemoveList {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        List<Student> studentList = null;
        try{
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>(){{
            add(new Student(12,"Tom"));
            add(new Student(14, "Jack"));
            add(new Student(15, "Julean"));
            add(new Student(16, "Doughlas"));                
            add(new Student(17, "Bathsheba"));
        }};

        for(Iterator<Student> itr = studentList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

        System.out.println(studentList.remove(new Student(12)));

        for(Iterator<Student> itr = studentList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Now my question is, is it safe removing an item from ArrayList as i have done in the above code,

does hashCode() plays a role in removing of the Student object from Collection,

Do we have a better approach,

Comment: Why do you have that `try-catch` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe the way you implemented because of your `equals()` can try to cast an object that is not a Student. You should treat it:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    //-- add it to your code --//
    if(o == this) 
        return true;

    if(!(o instanceof Student)) 
        return false;

    //-- at this point you're safe to cast --//

    Student student = (Student) o;
    boolean flag = false;
    if(this.getId() == student.getId()){
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

`hashCode()` doesn't play a role in this case.

Comment: `if(o == null)` case is not needed. Will be handled by `instanceof`. Also, last 5 lines can be replaced with - `return this.getId() == student.getId();`

Comment: Btw, the `o == this` although is not obligatory is a way to try to make things faster. This is a small method, but it could be bigger and could used several times.

Comment: I tried to preserve the original method, that's why I didn't make the last lines better. I'm just making it safe.

Answer (score 5):

> does hashCode() plays a role in removing of the Student object from Collection,

No. `equals()`  method takes role.

For example , just look at the [source code of ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29) `remove()`  method

```
>public boolean  remove(Object o) {
440         if (o == null) {
441             for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
442                 if (elementData[index] == null) {
443                     fastRemove(index);
444                     return true;
445                 }
446         } else {
447             for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
448                 if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {  //here
449                     fastRemove(index);
450                     return true;
451                 }
452         }
453         return false;
454     }
```

> Is it safe removing an item from Array List as i have done in the above code.

That *safe*  depends on your *Equal* definition of `Student` , Since you are telling if Id's are equal, then Student equals hence it's safe(not talking about threads).

Answer (score 1):

Your question

> is, is it safe removing an item from ArrayList as I have done in the above code,

Yes, it is safe (I am thinking safe as thread-safe or it is right to use by supplying object as parameter) because when `remove` function in invoked no other thread is performing any other operation.

> does hashCode() plays a role in removing of the Student object from Collection,

No, `hashCode()` don't plays a vital role when you invoke `Arraylist` remove function. If you look at the [source code for remove function](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29) then you see remove compares object by using function `equals` so the function `equals` overridden  plays a role in comparision.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the role of hashcode in the removal?